# Difference between http2_max_field_size and large_client_header_buffers?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty

On my Nginx server, I have some unwanted log :

```
[warn] the "http2_max_header_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead
```

Is it possible to remove those log ?

If not, could you please help me understand how to change http2_max_header_size and http2_max_field_size to large_client_header_buffers ?

Those value are set as follow :

```
http2_max_field_size 16k;
http2_max_header_size 64k;
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

According to [this commit](https://hg.nginx.org/nginx/rev/827202ca1269)

> HTTP/2: removed http2_max_field_size and http2_max_header_size.
>
> Instead, size of one large_client_header_buffers buffer and all large
> client header buffers are used.

you should replace

```
http2_max_field_size 16k;
http2_max_header_size 64k;
```

with

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k
```

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers

> Syntax:   **large_client_header_buffers** *number* *size*;

- 64k / 16k -> 4 (number of buffers)
- http2_max_field_size 16k -> 16k (buffer size)